# How to change the label class of bootstrap to break line when text is too big?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap do make an html page and I have this code:

```
<h4> <span class="label label-warning">Observation: @document.Observation</span></h4>
```

When this Observation variable comes longer I would like to break a line, how can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bootstrap Labels aren't really designed for multiple lines/long bodies of text but something like the following would work:

http://www.bootply.com/rUZ6CHwj7k

An alert might be more suitable? `<div class="alert alert-warning">...</div>`
the `.label` style is great for inline where the alert is better for block styles & more text.

More here:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels